# How to set large Background Image

Tags: html, css

I have a design in PSD format and I am converting that into HTML/CSS. I want to set a big image in back ground that appear behind header as well. Can any one tell me how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: [HTML body background.](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_body_background.asp)

Comment: The <body> background attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.
use CSS syntax: <body style="background-image:url(bgimage.jpg)">

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```css
body {
  background: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQxC6tuHBQvtvENnQRI-7iRaEfqigj-cuacu1IeYYXBmYD1J9VrJQ");
  
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h1{
color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="header">

    <h1>Header</h1>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only in `<header>` for example, you need to add the following CSS code.

```
header {
  background-image: url('path-to-image');
  background-position: relative; /* This depends on your preferences */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

You can also do it like this if you add the `<img>` in your `<header>`

```
header img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* or height: 100vh */
}
```